# Adding Tooltips with GreaseMonkey Javascript

Tags: javascript, firefox, hover, greasemonkey, mouseover

I~ would like to add tool tips to already existing text that may appear on some pages. This is to create a Greasemonkey script in Firefox just to help speed up some processes for us at work instead of checking a reference sheet over and over.

For example, say guests can submit a post that says they either want a cat, dog, or snake. So, unpredictably, you see a post that mentions either a cat, dog, or snake on the screen.

I'd want to be able to mouse/hover over the result, no matter which one, to get a specific tool tip for each.

Say someone submitted cat. If I go to just hover over the word cat, "meow" appears in a tooltip.

If they submitted dog, "woof" appears in a tool tip.

If they submitted snake, "hiss" appears in a tool tip.

Obviously this isn't really what it's for, but the list of things I want to do this for is fairly long, about 20-30 items. I've learned a fair amount of javascript but not for mouseovers like this, so if I can get a basic GreaseMonkey guideline/outline, I can finish the rest myself.

Also a side note: In the future, if I were to test out coding on JSFiddle for Firefox GM settings, what Frameworks/EXT, LOAD TYPE settings would I use?
And since it is a userscript, I cannot use any third party settings.

Comment: Did you look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22784677/using-onmouseover-to-display-tooltip-in-javascript) SO question?

Comment: I did. I'm looking for help specifically for GreaseMonkey, not within an HTML script. Also, cannot use any third party settings in a userscript.